# Prove that $\sin x+\tan x>2x,$ when $0 <x <\pi/2$

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve the question by following these steps.                    (1 ) Finding  $f'(x)$  i.e $\cos x +\sec^2x -2$ (I assumed $f(x)= \sin x+\tan x-2x$).                                                                                          (2)  $f'(x)$ is  (1-cosx)(cosx+sin^2x)/cosx which is positive implying it is strictly increasing.                                                                                In my book after these steps they have done  $f (x )>f (0)$     .                                                                                               Can someone please explain me this step. I know that 0 is a critical point but how can we compare them when '0' doesn't lie on the strictly increasing domain.

Comment: its $\pi$, pi not pie

Comment: It's kind of unreasonable to expect us to guess the idea behind a step in a proof in some unnamed book when you've given so little detail about the rest of the proof. (Such as the exact words the book used when "equating" $f(x)$ and $f(0)$, and anything that came after that point.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\cos x \ge \cos^2x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$, we have: $f(x) = \sin x + \tan x - 2x, x \in (0,\pi/2)\implies f'(x) = \cos x+\sec^2x-2\ge \cos^2x+\sec^2x -2 = \left(\cos x - \sec x\right)^2\ge 0\implies f(x) > f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

hINT: let $$f(x)=\sin(x)+\tan(x)-2x$$ then we have $$f'(x)=\cos(x)-2+\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$$
this is equivalent to
$$f'(x)=\left(1-\cos(x)\right)\left(\frac{1+\cos(x)-\cos(x)^2}{\cos(x)^2}\right)$$
we have $$f'(x)\geq 0$$ and $$f(0)=0$$